# PHP/JS Unlimited scroll loading all data from MySQL in one scroll

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was working on Unlimited scroll for my website using PHP and JavaScript. I almost made it but there was a problem In my code, after scrolling to the bottom of the page my script should load 15 articles every time I scroll to the bottom and after its done It stops loading more posts, but instead it loads all of the articles and then stops the script when all of the posts are loaded.

My JavaScript code:

```
<script>
// Unlimited Scroll
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.post-load').hide();
    var load = 0;
    var nbr = "<?php echo mysql_num_rows($sql); ?>";
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $('.post-load').show();
            load++;
            if (load * 15 > nbr) {
                $('.post-load').hide();
            } else {
                $.post("extensions/ajax.php", {
                    load: load
                }, function(data) {
                    $('.lb').append(data);
                    $('.post-load').hide();
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

extensions/ajax.php File for loading the posts through PHP:

```
<?php 

include 'connect.php';

$load = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['load'])) * 2;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY postNum DESC");
$countBlop = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$queryL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY postNum DESC LIMIT 15,".$countBlop."");

while ($posts = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryL)) {

?>

<div class="article">Echo the posts...</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your `LIMIT` syntax is backwards

`LIMIT 15,".$countBlop.`

should be

`LIMIT ".$lastIndex.",15`

As is now it would be starting at record 15 and then continuing to load until you reach the total count(as defined by $countBlop)

You will also need to have a way for jQuery to pass the last index to the ajax call.

Comment: How is the $lastIndex variable getting set?  How are you passing it to the ajax call?

Comment: I used the `$countBlop` not `$lastIndex`

Comment: I don't have a variable named `$lastIndex`

Comment: Right, but your code appears to be incorrect in that aspect, as there is no limit on the query giving data to $countBlop
`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY postNum DESC");`
`$countBlop = mysql_num_rows($sql);`

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you need to create a variable to the effect of $lastIndex, since $countBlop is a total number of records as it's currently written.

Comment: Ok, I changed the `$sql` variable to `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postNum DESC LIMIT 15");` added `LIMIT`

Comment: You mean I need to create variable and store the total # of posts?

Comment: That will result in the same 15 posts every time.
you need to use full syntax for LIMIT, `LIMIT _offset_,_increments_` where the offset sets the starting record number and the increments tells how many to get after that.  Each time your scroll trigger is hit, it would need to update the offset value by another 15.

Comment: I set the offset to `$load` and increment to `$countBlop`

Comment: It just loads all the posts. I don't know what to do I'm confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91888/discussion-between-arqetech-and-andrew-coder).

Comment: Look up mysql limit clause and read up on it.  There is a third variable you need to work with which would track the last record that was loaded and then be modified before the next load so you get neither the same posts nor ALL posts.  sorry if I'm not explaining well.

Comment: About to be driving for an hour, sorry.